# What are the rules for lifetimes in Rust when using boxed trait objects?

Tags: rust, traits, smart-pointers, lifetime

The code below doesn't compile with error E0597: borrowed value (two) doesn't live long enough.

```
fn main() {
    let one = String::from("one");

    let mut _it: Box<dyn Iterator<Item=char>> = Box::new(one.chars());

    let two = String::from("two");

    _it = Box::new(two.chars());
}
```

But, if instead of boxed trait object I use reference to a trait object it works:

```
fn main() {
    let one = String::from("one");

    let mut _it: &dyn Iterator<Item=char> = &one.chars();

    let two = String::from("two");

    _it = &two.chars();
}
```

Also, if I don't use trait object it works too:

```
fn main() {
    let one = String::from("one");

    let mut _it: Box<_> = Box::new(one.chars());

    let two = String::from("two");

    _it = Box::new(two.chars());
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 2):

Let's take them one by one.

In your first example, the problem is subtle and hinted at by the error message

```
8 |     _it = Box::new(two.chars());
  |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
9 | }
  | -
  | |
  | `two` dropped here while still borrowed
  | borrow might be used here, when `_it` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `Box<dyn Iterator<Item = char>>`
  |
  = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are defined
```

As the note says, values are dropped in the opposite order they are defined. As `two` is defined in line 6 and `_it` is defined (not *assigned*) in line 4, the compiler will try to destroy `two` before it tries to destroy `_it` at the end of the function. But by the time we reach the end of the function, `_it` holds a reference to `two` (line 8), and the imposed ordering would destroy `two` while `_it` still holds a reference to it. The destructor of `_it` *could* observe the destroyed value `two`, so this is not allowed.

Why is there even a destructor? Because the trait object `dyn Iterator...` - just like any other trait object - *could* hold some dynamic type that has a destructor. And that destructor might observe things it potentially references; as far as the compiler knows, that's `two`. While the actual `Chars`-type does not suffer from this problem, I could conjure up such a type and stick it into a `dyn Iterator...`. So with trait objects, the order in which values are dropped is always important.

The solution is to change the order of definition:

```
fn main() {
    let one = String::from("one");

    let two; // Notice the definition, before `_it` so it gets dropped *after*

    let mut _it: Box<dyn Iterator<Item=char>> = Box::new(one.chars());

    two = String::from("two");

    _it = Box::new(two.chars());
}
```

In the second example, you are using plain references. Since plain references do not have destructors, there is no destructor that could potentially observe a destroyed value while it is running, and the order in which values are destroyed is not important; so it compiles just fine.

In the third example, there are no trait objects involved, the boxed type is simply a normal type as far as the compiler is concerned (just like `Box<u32>`). Because it is a concrete type, the compiler can figure out that the type inside the `Box` (which is a `Chars`, and holds a reference of some lifetime), has a trivial destructor (which does nothing), and therefore the `Box` has a trivial destructor that simply deallocates; so it doesn't matter that `two` is in fact destroyed before `_it`, because `_it` will definitely not be able to observe `two` in its destructor.

Comment: Another option, which might be a bit more obvious in its intent to someone reading the code, would be to `drop(_it)` explicitly at the end of the function.

Comment: Well, if I explicitly add drop(_it) the error is still there.

Comment: Is there a way to add a trait bound to exclude possible types with destructor?

Comment: @basilefff: No, there is always at least a pointer to the `impl Drop` in any dyn type

Comment: @user2722968 can you explain why drop(_it) doesn't work?

Comment: @basilefff I can't, but I suspect that the drop-scope of `_it` get's extended to the end of the function due to the new binding on the last line, and the compiler bails out before realizing that it doesn't need to